# Como receber um modelo de data especifica no C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, entity-framework, rest

Estou fazendo uma api rest em C# que recebe nos parâmetros os dados de um cartão de crédito, estou tendo dificuldades em entender como eu posso passar uma data especifica para a variável, que seria a data de validade do cartão, que recebe somente MM/YY, e que no body eu pudesse passar somente a data necessária *`"data_expiracao": "01/2025"`* por exemplo.

***Classe Cartao.cs***

```
public class Cartao
{
    public string titular { get; set; }
    
    [CreditCard(ErrorMessage = "Cartão de crédito inválido")]
    public string numeroCartao { get; set; }
    public DateTime data_expiracao { get; set; }
    public string bandeira { get; set; }
    public string cvv { get; set; }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

você pode apenas enviar uma string para o front com a data já convertida
Ao invés de um Datetime, você usa uma string na classe

```
public class Cartao
{
    public string titular { get; set; }
    
    [CreditCard(ErrorMessage = "Cartão de crédito inválido")]
    public string numeroCartao { get; set; }
    public string data_expiracao { get; set; }
    public string bandeira { get; set; }
    public string cvv { get; set; }
}
```

e na hora de passar o valor você pode converter a data

```
dataCartao = data.ToString("MM/yyyy");
```

referencias:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1